# Why autolayout behaves different in iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, autolayout, constraints

For example: I have set in a `storyboard` scene a vertical space constraint from de bottom of a `UIButton` to the bottom of the superview with a constant of 20. When running in an iOS 8 device, this is correctly shown, but when running in an iOS 7 device, it looks like this constant becomes higher and the button is shown upper in the screen... I don't understand why this happens, since `autolayout` is supposed to be available since iOS 7.

Any help? I don`t know how to handle this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

One of new things in iOS 8 is the Layout Margin. Layout Margin is a new property available in UIView for iOS 8. So, any objects inherit from UIView will have this property. If you are developing the app for both iOS 7 and iOS 8, you should not use Layout Margin (or use layout margin in a smart way).

So, if you have any constraints related to layout margin and you didn’t do a proper check before launching the app on iOS 7 devices, the app might crash or the arrangement of the objects might be out of order.

Whenever you are trying to add new constraints from the storyboard in XCode 6, “Constrain to Margins” is ticked by default. The meaning of this selection is to add constraints with the new property in iOS 8.

If the deployment target of your app is iOS 7 and above and any of your constraints have this layout margin, the XCode will complain with the warning “**Layout attributes relative to the layout margin on iOS prior to 8.0″.**

If you are developing the app for both iOS 7 and 8, it is best to “Untick” the Constrain to Margins.

[Reference: you should also check this great tutorial](http://mobileoop.com/auto-layout-advanced-techniques-for-ios-8-and-7-using-xcode-6-on-storyboard)

Comment: Also, whenever you create a constraint in IB and you see the word Margin in the constraint, you can get the constraint without the Margin thing if you press 'alt' key.